# null_session or exception for rails api app with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a rails app made mainly for api purposes but it will probably have something like `Active admin` in the future, what option should I use for `protect_from_forgery`

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

or

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

ps I did notice the commented out text `# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is that you can conditionally determine which requests should be protected and which should not. For example, you could skip it for any requests to your API but leave it enabled for Admin actions if you so desired:

```
protect_from_forgery only: :admin_action?
```

Where admin_action? is a helper that knows whether or not the current action is being performed within the ActiveAdmin space. You can read more in the documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html